Undefined symbol sk_free when running C code with Python
I have some legacy code that uses a vendor library for openssl. The command that I am running is something like this:
gcc -shared -o mylib.so -fPIC libs/mylib.c -Ilibs/deps -Ideps/vendor/openssl/include -Ideps/vendor/openssl/lib.LINUX -lcrypto -lssl

And trying to run the code with Python ctypes like this:
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL('./mylib.so')

While I try to run, it gives me this error that sk_free is not defined:
OSError: ./mylib.so: undefined symbol: sk_free

I don't understand if I am missing something or if openssl library was compiled for 32 bits while the new system has 64 bits. Should I install other Linux libraries ?

If you're running on Linux, please add the output from ldd -r mylib.so to your question.  You can use the Edit button to do that.
